# Ruby C extension rb_str_new2 seems to return false

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I cannot post my actual code due to work copyright, so I will try to show my problem with simple example code.

I have a C extension whose simplified version looks like:

```
#include <ruby.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

VALUE test(VALUE self, VALUE string);
void Init_module_name() {
     module_name = rb_define_module("Modulename");
     c_modulename = rb_define_class_under(modulename, "Class", rb_cObject);
     rb_define_method(c_modulename, "test", test, 1);

     e_ModuleNameError = rb_define_class_under(modulename, "Error", rb_eStandardError);
}

VALUE test(VALUE self, VALUE string) {
    char *c_string = StringValueCStr(string);
    int fd = open(c_string, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (fd == -1) {
       rb_raise(e_ModuleNameError, "Failed to open file");
    }
    if (!isatty(fd)) {
       rb_raise(e_ModuleNameError, "File is not a tty");
    }

    struct termios config;
    int termios_ret = init_termios(config, fd)
    if (termios_ret != OK) { // OK defined by enum in modulename's header
        close(fd);
        rb_raise(e_ModuleNameError, "Termios init failed.");
    }

    int success = write(fd, "I'm a string", str_length);
    if (success < str_length) {
        close(fd);
        rb_raise(e_ModuleNameError, "Failed to write to file.");
    }

    close(fd);
    return rb_str_new2("Success");
}
```

Then, the ruby code that requires this looks like:

```
require 'modulename'

class ModuleName
  attr_acessor :file

  def initialize(file)
    @file = file
    @object = Modulename::Class.new
  end

  def test
    @object.test @file
  end
end
```

Which is then called in my production project like:

```
require "modulename_ruby_file"

x = ModuleName "/dev/pts/1"
x.test
```

Here is the interesting thing. When I run this code in production, the return value from x.test above is false (As in literally the value false, not a string). Also, the write to the file never happens. However, if I do it in some simplified test code it returns the string "Success" just like expected and the write is indeed completed.

Does anyone know of any situation that would cause this function not to execute the write, and return false? I already tried putting a rescue around it in case it was throwing one of the rb_raises, but it doesn't appear to be.

Me and 3 other members of my team have looked at this all afternoon and have not found an answer.

Comment: I think the example code needs some edits. What is `@console` for example? Is it in fact `@object`?

Comment: As far as I can see, your example C extension method `test` will either return the string 'Success', or raise an error. Are you actually able to replicate the fault using this code? I suspect there is a good chance the parts of it that you have chosen to extract do not, in fact, demonstrate your problem.

Comment: In fact I'd expect an environment problem, or something really simple such as not re-building your extension when deploying to production environment.

Comment: @NeilSlater You were correct about `@console` supposed to be `@object`. Fixed it in original. In any case, I wouldn't be surprised if it is something in the environment too. The problem is I can't think of any situation where the method should return false.

Comment: This may be one of those situations where you are not running the code you think you are. For instance a gem build or deployment failure may leave you with a previous version being called in production. If your production code has autoloaders anywhere, they could be hiding breakage as well.

Comment: @NeilSlater In case it didn't notify you automatically, I found the answer to this and posted it. I'm new to actually having a login for stackoverflow, if there is anyway I can give you rep even though I ended up answering this myself, let me know.

Comment: @mordocal. In this case, you fixed your own problem. I just gave some vague pointers, not the answer, and I didn't think of namespace clashes - I think I get +2 for upvote on a comment, so feel free to up a comment that pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this out, and it was very similar to what @NeilSlater was saying in the comments on the question.

We added a TON of debugging to the C code and had it write to a log file, and figured out that the C function (test in my example) was literally never being called. So, we looked at the symbol table for the .so and the assembly code gcc was generating and both looked fine. Finally we just said, "Let's change the name of the function and see if that helps" and... it worked. The actual function was named logout, and changing it to project_name_logout worked, so apparently there was some kind of namespace collision. So, much like @NeilSlater said, it had something to do with the environment!

So, for anyone else finding this on google: Add a "namespace" to your C code by prefixing all functions with your project name and you should be able to avoid this issue. [One of the other members mentioned, after the fact, that this was a good practice in C anyway.]

Note: We did not take the time to track down what was colliding with logout.

Comment: Please [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/183358) so that the question is marked answered in all the summaries.  This helps people who want to answer questions avoid wasting time on questions that have already been answered